# Node - How to make sure everything gets done in an async enviroment

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I'm not new to programming, but I am getting into Node.JS.  I understand blocking vs non-blocking operations. I understand that pushing things to non-blocking is Good Thing™.  What I'm trying to understand is how do I make sure, if I push things asynchronously, how can I make sure the program has collected all the data from all the different requests before continuing on to processing/return?

Below is some sample code using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql).  For the sake of argument it could be anything (Mongo, MySQL, file reads, http requests, etc), because I realize the mysql module has the capability to parallel itself.

```
function getUserInfo(userID, myDB){
    var users, profile, login;

    // Get all of the account data
    myDB.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='"+userID+"' LIMIT 0,1", function(err, row){
        users = JSON.stringify(row);
    }

    // Get all of the profile data
    myDB.query("SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `id`='"+userID+"' LIMIT 0,1", function(err, row){
        profile = JSON.stringify(row);
    }

    // Find their last logged in IP
    myDB.query("SELECT `ip`,`date` FROM `login` WHERE `userid`='"+userID+"' ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 0,1", function(err, row){
        login = JSON.stringify(row);
    }

    // Do some other processing here... Once all mysql is done.

    return(users, profile, login);
}
```

Is the answer here simply to dump all these calls into [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) and call it a day?

Comment: In one word **yes** that's exactly what async.js does for you. Don't trust me, just check the source! It's perfectly readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, if you need to do several things at once, a promise library can help ball that up nicely.  Also, you cannot simply `return` at the end of this function.  You need to accept a callback (unless your function is returning a promise of its own), and then call that callback once you are done with your queries.  Your callbacks to MySQL will happen long after this function has returned.

Finally, use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks.